# How to get files that have been checked in a certain number of times in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Is there a way to get, in TFS, all the files that have been checked in / updated an X number of times? I currently have an ASP.NET MVC project and am using TFS preview for VS 2012.

Comment: I've got a few ideas but the efficiency of the solution depends on the size of your project and history. Roughly how many files do you have in TFS? How many changesets do you have? What is X roughly in your example above?

Comment: I have around 50 files, 400 changesets, and X would be 1 or 2.

Answer (score 1):

While slow, the best way to do this is going to be running QueryHistory on each of the files you have checked into version control.  If you count the number of changesets that come back, that will tell you the number of times that file has been updated.

Basically you want to do something like this:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection("http://server:8080/tfs/collection";
VersionControlServer vcs = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
{
     var changesets = vcs.QueryHistory(filePath, ...);

     // Do your counting logic here
}
```

Again, that isn't going to run terribly fast but it is the best way to answer the question you are trying to answer.  If X were larger than 1 or 2 then we could come up with a better algorithm that called QueryHistory on the root and worked its way down in a depth-wise to hopefully prune out some portions of the tree.

Comment: would it be faster to grab the queryhistory of the parent folder and looping through the changesets counting the files instead?

Comment: That would work as well but would need to mean you would want to includeChanges as you brought down each changeset and would need to keep track of what you have seen as you process each changeset.  It also means you have to go through every changeset in your project (where the above solution could avoid that if they only wanted to check certain files).  This is good to bring up though.  There are cases where this approach would be more performant.